# Last Crusade motorcycle

Tags: indiana-jones, indiana-jones-and-the-last-crusade

In Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade, what motorcycle did he drive around with his father (Sean Connery) in the sidecar?

Was that model of motorcycle period-appropriate for the movie?  If not, what model of motorcycle would have been more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That motorcycle was a Dnepr MT11, according to [this web page](http://www.therpf.com/showthread.php?t=76781) and [this other web page](http://www.imcdb.org/vehicle_78946-Dnepr-MT-11-1988.html).